# cannot install mysql-connector-java, no package available

Tags: mysql, jdbc, centos

I need to install JDBC for MySQL running in CentOS.

I tried using this command

> yum install mysql-connector-java

but it says

> No Package mysql-connector-java available
>
> Nothing to do

Do you know any other command that aims to install JDBC?

Comment: Try to download from here : http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/

Comment: Hi @Taiki after downloading and decompressing, where am I supposed the extracted file? thanks :)

Comment: If you use Tomcat, follow this link for more instruction: http://gaveen.owain.org/2008/03/howto-setup-mysql-connectorj-51-for.html. In case of coding, just add the extracted file to library in you IDE to begin coding

Comment: @Taiki No, Im not using Tomcat.Im using monkeyrunner, it is jython. is the procedure the same with tomcat?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did to solve the issue:

1. Download the JDBC [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)
2. Extract the files anywhere you want. To extract follow the command below

> tar -zxvf [TAR FILENAME]

- You will find mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar inside that folder. Copy that and paste to (in my case) /%android-sdk%/tools/lib
- Add the new location of mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar to classpath

Answer (score 0):

mysql java connector is platform independent. you can download it from following link
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

you can put jar file in /lib/  or /webapps//web-inf/libs

I am assuming that you are using tomcat.

Thank you